# How do I properly fill my custom data structure for use in the A* algorithm? (WARNING: LONG)

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

**If you want the TLDR without context:** *I need help figuring out how to properly define and fill a data structure from a 2D array for a pathfinding algorithm.* Scroll to the bottom for my code.

I'm developing a game (early version available for viewing/playing on my [github](https://github.com/Remixt/Project-Ice-Runner)) For those curious about the map making program specifically, here is a [link to that directory on my github](https://github.com/Remixt/Project-Ice-Runner/tree/master/Ice%20Runner/src/Map%20Creation%20Tool/team10).

If you just want to see how the game functions to get a better grasp, here is a [video demo](https://youtu.be/rKxdbytKNtA).

The game itself loads maps utilizing LUA, and I made a simple map maker to generate Lua using the [Swing library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) in Java.

Basic Premise:

[image: Ice Runner in 2 Player Mode]

1. Navigate to the Goal of the map from the designated starting position.
2. Once a player starts moving, you can't stop or change directions until you hit a wall. Also you can't move diagonally.

   [image: Pokemon Ice Tunnel]
3. Players can make their own maps and challenge their friends.

**I want to restrict players to making only *valid* (winnable) maps to avoid frustration.** - How do I best accomplish this in your opinion?

The A* algorithm I believe is my best starting point for a method like this. However, I need to wrap my head around defining a valid path.

My maps in Java are currently represented as a **2D Array** of Image Icons. (For now)

The buttons can have 1 of 4 properties:

1. Empty - represents the floor, IE a normal navigatable part of the map.
2. Wall - represents a wall, Players will be stopped when coming into contact.
3. Start - represents where the player will start on the map.
4. Goal - represents the tile where the player will have completed the map.

Here is what I have (algorithm not included since its currently nothing different from a typical example on wiki)

```
    class Tile {

        JLabel payload = null; // wall, empty, goal, start
        Tile up = null;
        Tile down = null;
        Tile left = null;
        Tile right = null;
    }

// Fill and return a list with the information for each tile on the map
public static ArrayList<Tile> checkMapStatus(JLabel[][] map){
    ArrayList<Tile> mapList = new ArrayList<Tile>();

    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < map.length; j++){

        // create the surrounding tiles around the current tile (needs fixing)
        Tile tile = new Tile();
        Tile tileUp = new Tile();
        Tile tileDown = new Tile();
        Tile tileLeft = new Tile();
        Tile tileRight = new Tile();

        tile.payload = map[i][j];

        if(map[j + 1] != null) // prevent accessing inexistant array position
        tileUp.payload = map[i][j+1]; 

        if(j > 0) // prevent accessing inexistant array position
        tileDown.payload = map[i][j-1];

        if(i > 0) // prevent accessing inexistant array position
        tileLeft.payload = map[i-1][j];

        if(map[i + 1] != null) // prevent accessing inexistant array position
        tileRight.payload = map[i+1][j];

        tile.up = tileUp;
        tile.down = tileDown;
        tile.left = tileLeft;
        tile.right = tileRight;

        mapList.add(tile);

        }
    }
        return mapList;
}
```

**Issues with the above code:**

I'm creating tile objects that aren't technically connected to eachother right? That is, the up down left and right tiles aren't ever referenced again once created, so I'm creating 5 tiles when really I should only be creating 1 and refering the existing ones. How do I fix this in Java?

**Possibility for efficiency?** Would it be better for me to only define the wall, goal and starting tiles since the other ones are technically empty space?

Comment: Your example code won't even compile. `JLabel[i][j]` is an invalid expression. `i + 1 != null` is invalid because it's comparing a primitive to `null`.

Comment: Youtuber TheChernoProject did a 2-D gaming tutorial awhile back that goes through an implementation of the A* search algorithm and loading game maps.  I don't recall if he added a map validator though.  Either way, it may contain some helpful information related to your actual question.

Comment: Sorry about that @mypetlion, I'll have it fixed in a jiffy. I was using the built in editor to type it out so I didn't notice the syntax issue.

Comment: @mypetlion i believe its fixed, I'll throw it into an IDE to confirm.

Comment: @mrogers appreciate it, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to start off with a `Tile[][] temp` variable to help with the objects referencing eachother, and flatten it as you go. It's slightly less efficient, but not enough to worry about if this is just to initialize things.

```
public static ArrayList<Tile> checkMapStatus(JLabel[][] map){
    ArrayList<Tile> mapList = new ArrayList<Tile>();
    Tile[][] temp = new Tile[map.length][];

    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        temp[i] = new Tile[map[i].length];
        for(int j = 0; j < map.length; j++){

        // create the surrounding tiles around the current tile (needs fixing)
        Tile tile = new Tile();
        temp[i][j] = tile;

        tile.payload = map[i][j];
        //Just look up and to the left, populate the existing Tiles as you populate the current one
        if(i > 0 && j < temp[i-1].length){
            tile.up = temp[i-1][j];
            temp[i-1][j].down = tile;
        }
        if(j > 0){
            tile.left = temp[i][j-1];
            temp[i][j-1].right = tile;
        }


        mapList.add(tile);

        }
    }
    return mapList;
}
```

Comment: ahh, that makes perfect sense.